# Trying to understand how I should use a proxy when accessing a private API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, proxy

I am attempting to do some personal automation and am accessing a private api. 
I see that using a proxy is recommended, but I've never attempted this in the past so I'm a little unclear about how to implement such a feature in node.

I understand that a proxy masks your ip, but my confusion comes in at:

- what if that proxy gets blocked? Is there a way to automatically generate a new one?
- i heard there is an extra cost associated with it, is this true?

If there are any tutorials, npm packages, strategies that you would recommend I would love to hear.

My project is set up using typescript and express.

Comment: If by "private api" you mean "an api offered by someone but only within the bounds of a particular network and hence must be accessed by a particular proxy" then that directs the proxy you must use. Other than that I can't see why you particularly need a proxy. A proxy is just a computer that sits between you and the server passing requests on and responses back. It is not necessary if you can reach the server directly, adds a level of indirection, reduces performance and introduces an additional failure point

Comment: @CaiusJard with the package im using, they recommend i use one. So thats why im curious. I think its because if i make too many concurrent requests, it will block the im using.  So what then?

Comment: My questions would be: recommended by whom? What is the context? What do you think a proxy is? What do you think a proxy will offer you? Are you aware that questions asking for recommendations of libraries, learning materials, external resources etc are specifically off topic for stack overflow?

Comment: By the creators of the package I'm using. The context is my server querying an api elsewhere, and theres a chance their server will block mine if i make too many request. Thats a fair assumption right? My question is a general question about implementation  with javascript. If you want to recommend tools to make this easier, feel free. But that isn't the point of the question.

Comment: Fair assumption or not, it's not really a question we can deliver a fact based answer to because it's speculation itself. Perhaps find out off the oackagemaintainers why they recommend a proxy so that the specifics can be incorporated into an answer. If it's just to reduce the number of requests to less than x per second, you don't need a proxy for that, just some code that exhibits a bit of self control